# push last view from UIViewCOntroller

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Hi guys i have quick question, So i have uset UIViewController to push some views on my window based application and

here is the question:

```
Accessibility_view_Controller * accessibility_controller = [Accessibility_view_Controller alloc];
        accessibility_controller.path_for_save = self.path_2;
        accessibility_controller.Supporters_survey = [ self.Supporters_survey_mut objectAtIndex:row_value];
        accessibility_controller.Supporters_info = [self.Supporters_info_mut objectAtIndex:row_value];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:accessibility_controller animated:YES];

        [accessibility_controller release];
```

i am on the accessibility_controller view now but i want to move back to the view from where i called this, i mean the parentview , i know i can do it from navigation bar but i want to do it from tapping a row. SO what will be the code for pushing the  parent view controller of the accessibilty controller on the window.  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to go back. This is very well documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)